# Cannot log into ubuntu with standard account with ssh

Tags: ssh

On a ubuntu 16.04 server (OVH public cloud)

I create a standard account :

```
adduser www
```

I add my public key into .ssh/authorized_keys
Then I do a

```
ssh www@myserver
```

And I got :

```
Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root"
```

I was expecting "www" instead of "root", but not : strange.

The public key is correctly read because before setting it I got permission denied. In fact, the login process begins correctly because in auth.log I got :

```
May 14 09:12:42 serveur-1 sshd[16069]: Accepted publickey for www from 86.252.248.254 port 38686 ssh2: RSA SHA256:+X9bylqQgjb/bjeLL8P0AVx0WFJZloWXacKPE43oD4E
May 14 09:12:42 serveur-1 sshd[16069]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user www by (uid=0)
May 14 09:12:42 serveur-1 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user www by (uid=0)
May 14 09:12:42 serveur-1 systemd-logind[1291]: New session 27 of user www.
May 14 09:12:52 serveur-1 sshd[16129]: Received disconnect from 86.252.248.254 port 38686:11: disconnected by user
May 14 09:12:52 serveur-1 sshd[16129]: Disconnected from 86.252.248.254 port 38686
May 14 09:12:52 serveur-1 sshd[16069]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user www
May 14 09:12:52 serveur-1 systemd-logind[1291]: Removed session 27.
```

I know, I should do a ssh ubuntu@myserver and then use sudo, but I want to understand why I have this behaviour and how can I disable it to be able to log in a standard account directly with ssh

Any idea ?

Comment: Could you share string for wee user from your `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the real resaon : I copied my authorized_keys from root to the standard account, there was :

no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo 'Please login as the user \"centos\" rather than the user \"root\".';echo;sleep 10" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA2WA6Iao6j6yLs

In it.

So come the message...